# Multiple posts lists are getting created, How to Resolve?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am facing an issue like Multiple Posts Lists are getting created when i Create a site by using custom site template.
Site template contains multiple views and for each view separate post list is getting created.
please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Your not very clear in your question, are you saying that some lists are automatically created? as I don't think you can stop this as SharePoint needs to create a few forms and lists to give you a fully working site, if you don't need the lists you could just delete them using 'List settings' and then 'Delete this list'.